# How to configure stream replication from Vanilla Postgresql 9.6 DB to AWS RDS Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have external Postgresql 9.6 (outside AWS) and want to conduct replication to AWS RDS postgresql. I see there are certain parameters that need to be defined on AWS RDS but I am not sure where they are located at. For example, I can't find hot_standby in the "parameters group" of the RDS postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to modify a selected list of parameters in the AWS managed RDS instance for postgres. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Parameters) lists all the parameters available for postgresql server.

It does not list `hot_standby` parameter instead providing `hot_standby_feedback`. I assume that this means you can not set replication with a node outside of the RDS cluster.

There is documentation available for setting up replication for MySQL DB from outside RDS cluster [available here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html); however, I was unable to find something similar for postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same process described here [enter link description here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/migrate-from-self-managed-database-ec2-aws-rds-soumitra-sarkar)